# Getting error while submitting notebook on kaggle even after importing nltk library

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, kaggle

Used the below code for imorting the libraries.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('omw-1.4')
```

But after submitting the code always getting this error hence not able to make successful submission.
I tried downloading the `nltk` library as well but still issue did not get resolved. could someone help on this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Vx2.png)

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource omw-1.4 not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('omw-1.4')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load corpora/omw-1.4

  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/opt/conda/nltk_data'
    - '/opt/conda/share/nltk_data'
    - '/opt/conda/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing an issue with NLTK not finding some of its resources, for example as wordnet, in a Kaggle notebook, you might need to manually download and unzip them in a directory that NLTK can access.

Here's a Python code snippet that you can use to download and unzip the Wordnet and stopwords resources into the working directory of your Kaggle notebook:

```
import nltk
import subprocess

# Download and unzip wordnet
try:
    nltk.data.find('wordnet.zip')
except:
    nltk.download('wordnet', download_dir='/kaggle/working/')
    command = "unzip /kaggle/working/corpora/wordnet.zip -d /kaggle/working/corpora"
    subprocess.run(command.split())
    nltk.data.path.append('/kaggle/working/')

# Now you can import the NLTK resources as usual
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
```

This code first checks if the wordnet resources are already available in NLTK's search path. If not, it downloads them, and then, unzips the downloaded files into a corpora subdirectory of the working directory, which is a location that NLTK can access.

After running this code, you should be able to import the NLTK resources as usual, without encountering a LookupError.

Answer (score 1):

I used this method for TfidfVectorizer from sklearn. The same error but wasn`t found 'wordnet'. I think this solve can help

1. Download wordnet.zip from kaggle/output on your PC after nltk.download('wordnet')
2. Upload wordnet.zip from PC in kaggle/input using Dataset Title 'corpora'
3. Copy path from input and append it in nltk

   ```
   import nltk

   nltk.download("wordnet")

   nltk.data.path.append('/kaggle/input')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue with wordnet, so my problem looked like this:

```
Resource 'corpora/wordnet' not found. Please use the NLTK
Downloader to obtain the resource: >>> nltk.download()
```

I found this [discussion on kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/general/395169)

which says to unzip the file manually using this line:

```
!unzip /usr/share/nltk_data/corpora/wordnet.zip -d /usr/share/nltk_data/corpora/
```

It solved my case, maybe it can be useful here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, probably will solve the issue...

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

or

```
nltk.download('all')
```

Comment: Hi Sachin, I tried this but still getting this error when submitting in kaggle, In Jupyter Notebook it is working.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
nltk.download("wordnet")
```

use

```
!python -m nltk.downloader -d /kaggle/working/usr/share/nltk_data/ wordnet
```

Comment: I mean it is almost the same and I don't think it might solve the original problem